# How to add caption to my icon like this example?

Tags: icon, mobile, ios

I want to add text to my icon like this:

[image]

[image]

"Free" added to the icon. I had a contractor that did it for me in the past but she is no longer working for me. I want to do it myself.

What is the simplest way? What tools do I need?

Comment: What software/tools are you using? It's pretty basic editing (shape + gradient fill + text+drop shadow), so you might what to look at tutorials for the program you plan to use.

Comment: I just have an icon image in png.

Comment: Is it an icon in the sense of an .ico file, or only in the sense of a symbol?

Comment: @MMacD Just a single PGN file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an icon only in the sense that it's a symbol, you can add that banner in Photoshop or a similar bit editor.  This is how to do it in P'shop v7, which is what I own.  I imagine that the process is the same in newer versions.

First duplicate the layer with the original image, and hide the original (you'll be happy you did if you make a mistake).  Next create a new layer above the one with the original image (I suppose it's meant to be a chess knight), draw your banner, adjust it with layer stuff (drop shadow or whatever) til it looks the way you want it to look, and then "save for web" with both the layers visible.  You'll get a combination image.